# HTML paragraph, embedded span confusion

Tags: html, text, format, indentation, paragraph

I'm trying to figure out why this chunk of code below isn't resulting in what I expect it would, where each piece of text (Text #1, x, Text #2) shows up on its own line, and 'x' is slightly indented. Any insight as to where I'm going wrong?

```
  <p>TEXT #1
    <br /> <span style="text-indent: 2em;">x</span>
    <br />TEXT #2
  </p>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `span` he is `inline` by default
You must change the span display to `display: inline-block;`

```html
  <p>TEXT #1
    <br /> <span style="text-indent: 2em; display: inline-block;">x</span>
    <br />TEXT #2
  </p>
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<p>
    TEXT #1<br>
    <span style="padding-left: 2em;">x</span><br>
    TEXT #2
</p>
```

`<br>` is also the correct (HTML5) way of doing newline tags.